# one more empty P element?

Tags: javascript, html, web

```js
alert(document.getElementById('hhh').children[2].outerHTML)
```

```html
<h1 id = 'hhh'>
hhh1
<p id ="ppp"><p>para1</p>para2</p>
</h1>
```

Why h1 have 3 children ?

It should be 2, which are 2 P elements.

Why there's 1 more extra empty P elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nested P TAG.

```
<p id ="ppp"><p>para1</p>para2</p>
```

The above code will be rendered as:

```
<p id="ppp"></p>
<p>para1</p>
"para2"
<p></p>
```

- 1st p tag will automatically get a closing partner
- 2nd p tag and 3rd p closing tag will work properly as partner
- 4th p closing tag will generate an opening p tag to partner the leftover closing p tag. **therefore creating the 3rd P TAG**

I knew this by experience. I haven't dive deep why this is being rendered like this.

hope it's understandable and helped you.

Comment: But if it's nested div, it's another story : D